# How can i get data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do a user search vie search bar.when I enter the last name I should receive data about users if there are matches but i don't know how.

here is my try

```
searchBar(){
  let a=app.database().ref('users/'+app.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByChild('/surname').equalTo('Крюкин');
  console.log(a);
}
```

here is structure of data

[image]

Comment: Your `a` is a query, but you don't execute the query yet. You'll need to attach a listener with `once()` or `on()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists and one of the many tutorials that are available for Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
searchBar(){
      let a=app.database().ref('users');
        a.orderByChild('surname').equalTo('Крюкин').on('value',((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           console.log(childSnapshot.val());
     });
    }
```

First you are not using a userID, that's a random id generated using `push()` in your database. Therefore you need to use `forEach()` to access the data.

Check the guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

you dont exactly read data from firebase.

You should create a handle, which you did, a in your case
and then on that handle you register `value` event listener the code below is from official docs

```js
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // ...
  });
});
```

in your case you shloud just to

```
a.on("value",list=>{list.forEach(...)})
```

also you can subscribe for future child_added/removed/updated events

[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) are the docs